# backlight of windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

How can I detect using c# if state of backlight is turn on or turn off? After specified time, backlight turn off in mobile.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[GetDevicePower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447831.aspx) might be what you want.

there is a thread on msdn forums about this too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/673e6079-4d48-40ec-aab2-00827a460bcb

Comment: That's true assuming the OEM implemented the device with accordance to Microsoft's power manager. Seems to not always be the case - read http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/05/18/WhyWindowsMobileSucksACaseStudy.aspx